# Questions about an dynamics equation derivation

Tags: permutations, evolutionary-game-theory

When reading a paper, i find it's difficult to derive the following equation.

In the paper, authors define:

$f_A=(1-\omega)+\omega[(k-1)q_{A|A}*a+[(k-1)q_{B|A}+1]*b]$

$f_B=(1-\omega)+\omega[(k-1)q_{A|B}*c+[(k-1)q_{B|B}+1]*d]$

$g_A=(1-\omega)+\omega[[(k-1)q_{A|A}+1]*a+(k-1)q_{B|A}*b]$

$g_B=(1-\omega)+\omega[[(k-1)q_{A|B}+1]*c+(k-1)q_{B|B}*d]$

where $\omega \rightarrow 0$

Then, they say:

$$
\frac{1} {N} p_B\sum_{k_A=0}^k\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
k_A
\end{array}\right) q_{A|B}^{k_A}q_{B|B}^{k_B} \frac{k_A f_A}{k_A f_A+k_Bf_B} -\frac{1} {N} p_A\sum_{k_A=0}^k\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
k_A
\end{array}\right) q_{A|A}^{k_A}q_{B|A}^{k_B} \frac{k_B g_B}{k_A g_A+k_B g_B}
$$

where $k_A+k_B=k, p_A+p_B=1, q_{A|X}+q_{B|X}=1, p_{XY}=q_{X|Y}*p_Y, p_{AB}=p_{BA}$

equals to

$\omega \frac{k-1} {N} p_{AB}(I_aa+I_bb-I_cc-I_dd)+O(w^2)$

where

$I_a = \frac{k-1}{k}q_{A|A}(q_{A|A}+q_{B|B})+\frac{1}{k}q_{A|A}$

$I_b = \frac{k-1}{k}q_{B|A}(q_{A|A}+q_{B|B})+\frac{1}{k}q_{B|B}$

$I_c = \frac{k-1}{k}q_{A|B}(q_{A|A}+q_{B|B})+\frac{1}{k}q_{A|A}$

$I_d = \frac{k-1}{k}q_{B|B}(q_{A|A}+q_{B|B})+\frac{1}{k}q_{B|B}$

The detailed steps are omitted in the paper. So i wonder how to derive this equation. I have tried so many times, here is some of my thoughts:
The equation includes a Binomial distribution of r.v. $k_A$, therefore, does the sum symbol in the equation can be seen as an expection? But the denominator item also contains $k_A$, how can i deal with it?

I donot major in math, so i wonder is there any tricks or theorems that can be used to derive or simplify this equation?

The detailed information can be found in the supplementary in the paper link: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature04605